# css hyphens not working properly in chrome when using only two words

Tags: html, css

```css
.container {
      width: 250px;
      background-color: red;
    }

.hyphenate {
              width: 230px;
              font-size: 40px;
              margin-bottom: 0.6em;
              text-align: left;
              -ms-hyphens: auto;
              -moz-hyphens: auto;
              -webkit-hyphens: auto;
              hyphens: auto;
      }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="hyphenate">this    
  internationalization </h1>
</div>
```

I'm currently working on a web page, I have this  tag in which I want to apply hyphenation, I used multiple combinations of attributes in CSS

```
.hyphenate {
          font-size: 40px;
          margin-bottom: 0.6em;
          text-align: left;
          hyphens: auto;
          -ms-hyphens: auto;
          -webkit-hyphens: auto;
          -moz-hyphens: auto;
        }
```

this combination works perfectly in Firefox and Safari in both desktop and mobile versions, but I cannot get it to work in chrome, I have also tried other combination with **word-break**, **word-wrap** and **overflow-wrap** but the problem is still there.
I have also read that it is a chrome bug but according to the last information from https://caniuse.com/?search=hyphens, it states that there is partial support with the auto value.

Here is the example I'm using:
[this is the text breaking properly on Safari and firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGWti.png)

[this what I get when I open the page on chrome (both desktop and mobile)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vjq6t.png)
the Hyphenation works properly in chrome only when the header contains at least 3 words.
[and this what I get when I only use two words in chrome, it causes an overflow and does not break, but it breaks correctly in firefox and safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4rfp.png)
I'm using chrome on a mac with version 87.0.4280.88 which is currently the latest and android chrome version 87.0.4280.101
I would be thankful for any help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: [The rules defining how hyphenation is performed are not explicitly defined by the specification, so the exact hyphenation may vary from browser to browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens#try_it).

Answer (score 8):

This looks like [crbug.com/1022415](https://crbug.com/1022415), which was fixed in Chrome 89. It works as expected when I tried in my local test. For your snippet, you need to add the `lang="en"` attribute.

```css
.container {
      width: 250px;
      background-color: red;
    }

.hyphenate {
              width: 230px;
              font-size: 40px;
              margin-bottom: 0.6em;
              text-align: left;
              -ms-hyphens: auto;
              -moz-hyphens: auto;
              -webkit-hyphens: auto;
              hyphens: auto;
      }
```

```html
<div class="container" lang="en">
  <h1 class="hyphenate">this    
  internationalization </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: But why are hyphens not showing correctly? It looks like a missing glyph, see attached screenshot. Using Google Chrome v. 96 on macOS.

https://imgur.com/bEWLwK4

Answer (score 3):

If you have `word-break: break-all;` then auto-hyphenation doesn't work.

[According to yarusome@github](https://github.com/mdn/content/issues/26950#issuecomment-1561343773) (an MDN contributor), this is expected behaviour:

> `hyphens` has effect as long as `word-break` is not `break-all`, including the `normal` value effectively set by the legacy `break-wor`d value.
>
> This effect is expected in that `word-break: break-all` makes Latin letters break like CJK characters. [Section 5](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text/#ref-for-propdef-word-break) of CSS Text Module has detailed explanation and comparison on this.

They have added a note to the [MDN css/hyphens page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens) warning about this behaviour...

> If you apply word-break: break-all then no hyphens are shown, even if the word breaks at a hyphenation point.

Answer (score 0):

Just add word-wrap and overflow-wrap to fix this problem.

```
.hyphenate {
 word-wrap: break-word;
 overflow-wrap: break-word;
 -webkit-hyphens: auto;
 -moz-hyphens: auto;
 -ms-hyphens: auto;
 hyphens: auto;
}
```